# Como crear Respaldo de BD SqlServer desde C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Necesito Crear un respaldo y restaurarlo desde  C#

Para realizarlo desde Sql Managment Studio uso el siguiente codigo:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MiBD]
TO DISK = 'C:\Respaldo\Backup.BAK'
GO


USE master
RESTORE DATABASE MiBD
FROM DISK = 'C:\Respaldo\Backup.BAK' WITH REPLACE
```

Pero para hacerlo desde el programa estuve buscando soluciones y muchos usaban procedure pero no encontre un buen ejemplo para adaptarlo

Answer (score 4):

Para realizar tareas administrativas sobre el SQL Server deberías (recomendación) utilizar [SMO (SQL Server Management Objects)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo)

Uno de las utilidades/métodos que tiene es [Backup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup), que nos ayuda a realizar esta tarea mediante objetos en C# (que es lo que estas necesitando).
Y como toda componente ... desde la versión 2017 del motor viene en paquetes Nuget

- Nuget > [Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects)

Un ejemplo

```
            var backup = new Backup();
            var server = new Server( @"TuServidor\TuInstancia");
            backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            backup.Database = "StarwarsDB";
            backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"E:\DB\Backups\StarwarsDB-20190801.bak", DeviceType.File);
            backup.BackupSetName = "StarwarsDB-20190801";
            backup.Initialize = false;
            backup.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
            backup.Complete += Backup_Completed;

            backup.SqlBackup(server);
```

Como puedes ver... tienes eventos cuando se completan o de  progreso, para que puedas suscribirte desde el codigo e ir realizando acciones. Mucho mas facil asi con SMO que con scripts directos como estabas indicando y enviando con SQLCommand hacia el motoro. Tienes mejor administración de esta tarea. Por eso la recomendación de hacerlo de este modo.

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [SMO (SQL Server Management Objects)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo)
- [Backup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup)
- [Instalar SMO](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía